# AdWords - Download app engagement campaign report with Python

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I want to download app campaign report using python,
The code is working with App reports but not for App engagement campaigns please help

report_downloader = adwords_client.GetReportDownloader(version='v201809')

```
      # Create report query.
      report_query = (adwords.ReportQueryBuilder()                          .Select('CampaignId','CampaignName','CampaignStatus','CustomerDescriptiveName','AccountDescriptiveName','Date','DayOfWeek','Cost','Impressions','Clicks','Interactions','Engagements','TopImpressionPercentage','AbsoluteTopImpressionPercentage','Conversions')
                      .From('CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT')
                      .During('YESTERDAY')
                      .Build())
    
      # You can provide a file object to write the output to. For this
      # demonstration we use sys.stdout to write the report to the screen.
      report_downloader.DownloadReportWithAwql(
          report_query, 'CSV',output, skip_report_header=True,
          skip_column_header=True, skip_report_summary=True,
          include_zero_impressions=True)
      output.seek(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

App engagement campaigns are [not supported by the Adwords API](https://groups.google.com/g/adwords-api/c/E3kgM6-cRUU/m/4rWSIGFKBgAJ). You will need to use the newer [Ads API](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/start).